# execute query automatically in sql spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to do **java spring boot** *project*, where I have a table which has many columns,
**so** I have this query to update the data where their date <current_date,

```
UPDATE app_user 
SET `payant` = 0  
WHERE DATE_ADD(`creatdate_time`, INTERVAL +3 MONTH) <= CURRENT_DATE()
```

is it possible to excute this query automatically inside the spring project to get my data by created time after this query,

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"?

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a bit more what you are trying to achieve but, just in case, have you taken a look to `@Scheduled`?